# VIsual Studio 2019 Inactive code is not greyed out

Tags: c++, visual-studio

VS 2019 Community 16.1.4 (WIN10 x64 PRO)

Inactive code is not greyed out. 
Here is the specimen: https://snag.gy/jzJZEM.jpg

I have looked very carefuly in tools options, fonts and colors, etc. To no avail.
This was working in many years before. Not having it makes code sometimes very hard to read and understand.

How do I make/show/set inactive code greyed out?

**EDIT**

It turns out VS 2019 PRO has rectified this issue that was a genuine bug.
VS 2019 Community still has this problem.

I am doing my best not to comment this further...

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding? Are you using precompiled headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug of Intellisense. Give it some time or restart IDE.

Working on VS 2019 Pro 16.1.1

https://pasteboard.co/IlaQzer.png

Comment: Marked as answer, thanks. Sadly (or not) this works in VSCode. We must not swear in public and especially not on SO .. So I will write only this: It seems in C# based Visual Studio team there is no C++ developers.  How is this kind of a mistake even possible?